# Rest API FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject In Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest-api, force.com

> Hi All,

> I'm unable to fix the code and giving the error as "FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject " in test class.  I have implemented Apex class for rest API but having the issue with test Class. Could you some one help me on this?

> See Below apex class code,

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/GetContactId/*')
global without sharing class PersonContactRestEndpoint{
   
   @HttpGet
    global static string getPersonContactId() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        
        // grab the EmailId & Brand from the end of the URL       
        String EmailId= RestContext.request.params.get('emailId');
        String Brand= RestContext.request.params.get('brand');
         
        system.debug('EmailId==>'+emailId);      
        system.debug('Brand==>'+brand);
        
        Account CustomerId=  [SELECT PersonContactId FROM Account WHERE CC_Brand__c = :Brand AND PersonEmail = :EmailId LIMIT 1];
        String PersonContactId = CustomerId.PersonContactId;
        
        system.debug('PersonContactId==>'+PersonContactId);
        return PersonContactId;          
    }
}
```

> Test Class is below

```
@IsTest
private class PersonContactRestEndpointTest
{
    static testMethod void testGetMethod()
    {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name='Test';
        acc.AccountNumber ='12345';
        insert acc;
        
      // Create Required data here  
    
        Test.startTest();
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        
        req.params.put('PersonEmail', 'sschimpf@urbn.com');
        req.params.put('CC_Brand__c', 'Anthropologie');  // ==> CC_Brand__c is formula field
        req.params.put('PersonContactId', '0032h00000GfE6rAAF');
        
         req.httpMethod = 'Get';
         req.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // Add a JSON Header as it is validated 
        // req.requestURI= URL.getOrgDomainUrl() +'/services/apexrest/GetContactId?brand=Anthropologie&emailId=sschimpf@urbn.com';
         //req.requestURI= URL.getOrgDomainUrl() +'/services/apexrest/GetContactId';
         req.requestURI= '/services/apexrest/GetContactId';
         RestContext.request = req;
         RestContext.response = res;
         string results = PersonContactRestEndpoint.getPersonContactId(); 
        Test.stopTest();
        
    }
}
```

Is I'm missing anything? Thanks in advance for the help..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your test class you create an account

```
Account acc = new Account();
acc.Name='Test';
acc.AccountNumber ='12345';
insert acc;
```

but in the class under test you search for an account that is a person account and has to have `PersonEmail`set. As you haven't created a matching account, in the line

```
Account CustomerId=  [SELECT PersonContactId FROM Account WHERE CC_Brand__c = :Brand AND PersonEmail = :EmailId LIMIT 1];
```

there is no result, which creates an Exception.

Always first store all possible results in a list, and then check if there are actual results - you would always never be sure there will be a result.

So, first change the class under test to

```
List<Account> customers=  [SELECT PersonContactId FROM Account WHERE CC_Brand__c = :Brand AND PersonEmail = :EmailId LIMIT 1];
if (customers.size () > 0) {
    ... your code here ...
```

and second, do create a matching account in your test class, so that the class under test actually can find a result and work with that.